# XAML Custom Grid Border (Camera Viewfinder similar to dm77)

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, uwp, zxing.net

I'm trying to make a custom viewfinder for ZXing.Mobile. It should be similar to viewfinder for [dm77](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) (Android library). In original it looks like the picture below:

Original ViewFinder picture
[image: original viewfinder picture]

I have next XAML definition for the view:

```
<Grid Name="Overlay" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Rectangle Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeDashArray="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How can I make the border of view looks exactly like it does on the picture?

Comment: Convert the image into PNG format with the Black part as transparent and use that image instead of creating your own effect. It will be easy.

Comment: I've been thinking about it. But the border must be responsive to changing size of screen. A picture won't work in that case.

Comment: Image size can be dynamically changed. Give a minute, Let me give a try to create this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these lines of code. Change the values as you want.

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="500">
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" X2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" Y2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" X2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" Y2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" X2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" Y2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" X2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Line Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" Y2="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Line Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" X2="500" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @denisyfrolov It's my pleasure

Comment: @VijayNirmal I need help, Please ! In Visual Studio 2017 in Xamarin(Cross-Plataform) my xaml layout file has error : Type Line not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Comment: @MattBidas Please open a new question with all the codes than throws error

Comment: @VijayNirmal  Could you help me, please ? I need to create a custom page to Scanner Qr Code, but I did not understand the instructions of Github. Could you show me an example for Xamarin.Forms ? Thanks in advance!